# How do i create an executable for windows on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, wine

*I am working on a Mac.*
**I am trying to convert my PyQt application into an executable for windows.**

I have already tried to convert it  with wine and pyinstaller but i cant seem to understand how wine actually works.
If i want to create an executable for mac i use the following command:

```
pyinstaller -i icons/pdflogo.ico -w -F pdf_converter/main.py
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: see https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options

Comment: Isn't that talking about the case if i want to use pyinstaller on windows?

Comment: @Darjusch No, You can not. If you want to get an executable for windows then you must do it from windows

Comment: @Darjusch Wine emulates many things but has limitations. One possible option is that you use a virtual machine with windows on your MacOS and there you try to generate the executable